# Refactoring repetitive if statements from API call

Tags: javascript, if-statement, refactoring, openweathermap

I have used four very similar if statements in order to choose which weather icon to display for my weather app project.

I have tried using for loops, forEach, googling, experimenting but I can't quite seem to refactor it and keep the functionality.

I have taken the first four items of an array for weather forecasts from OpenWeatherMap, and depending on the weather code of a specific array (which represents a time), I display the respective icon.

I have the functionality but I have a lot of repeated code, will someone please help me refactor this or point me in the right direction? This is my first proper project so please be gentle! Thank you for any help in advance :)

```js
const getForecast = async (api) => {
    try {
        const res = await axios.get(api);
        console.log(res);

        const weather1 = res.data.list[0].weather[0].main;
        const time1 = res.data.list[0].dt_txt.substr(11, 15);
        const weather2 = res.data.list[1].weather[0].main;
        const time2 = res.data.list[1].dt_txt.substr(11, 15);
        const weather3 = res.data.list[2].weather[0].main;
        const time3 = res.data.list[2].dt_txt.substr(11, 15);
        const weather4 = res.data.list[3].weather[0].main;
        const time4 = res.data.list[3].dt_txt.substr(11, 15);

        forecastTime1.textContent = time1;
        forecastTime2.textContent = time2;
        forecastTime3.textContent = time3;
        forecastTime4.textContent = time4;

        if (weather1 === "Thunderstorm") {
            forecastDisplay1.src = `img/thunder.svg`;
        } else if (weather1 === "Drizzle") {
            forecastDisplay1.src = `img/drizzle.svg`;
        } else if (weather1 === "Rain") {
            forecastDisplay1.src = `img/rain.svg`;
        } else if (weather1 === "Snow") {
            forecastDisplay1.src = `img/snowy.svg`;
        } else if (
            weather1 === "Mist" ||
            weather1 === "Smoke" ||
            weather1 === "Haze" ||
            weather1 === "Dust" ||
            weather1 === "Fog" ||
            weather1 === "Sand" ||
            weather1 === "Ash" ||
            weather1 === "Squall" ||
            weather1 === "Tornado"
        ) {
            forecastDisplay1.src = `img/cloudy.svg`;
        } else if (weather1 === "Clear") {
            forecastDisplay1.src = `img/clear-${getDayOrNight()}.svg`;
        } else if (weather1 === "Clouds") {
            forecastDisplay1.src = `img/cloudy.svg`;
        }

        if (weather2 === "Thunderstorm") {
            forecastDisplay2.src = `img/thunder.svg`;
        } else if (weather2 === "Drizzle") {
            forecastDisplay.src = `img/drizzle.svg`;
        } else if (weather2 === "Rain") {
            forecastDisplay2.src = `img/rain.svg`;
        } else if (weather2 === "Snow") {
            forecastDisplay2.src = `img/snowy.svg`;
        } else if (
            weather2 === "Mist" ||
            weather2 === "Smoke" ||
            weather2 === "Haze" ||
            weather2 === "Dust" ||
            weather2 === "Fog" ||
            weather2 === "Sand" ||
            weather2 === "Ash" ||
            weather2 === "Squall" ||
            weather2 === "Tornado"
        ) {
            forecastDisplay2.src = `img/cloudy.svg`;
        } else if (weather2 === "Clear") {
            forecastDisplay2.src = `img/clear-${getDayOrNight()}.svg`;
        } else if (weather2 === "Clouds") {
            forecastDisplay2.src = `img/cloudy.svg`;
        }

        if (weather3 === "Thunderstorm") {
            forecastDisplay3.src = `img/thunder.svg`;
        } else if (weather3 === "Drizzle") {
            forecastDisplay3.src = `img/drizzle.svg`;
        } else if (weather3 === "Rain") {
            forecastDisplay3.src = `img/rain.svg`;
        } else if (weather3 === "Snow") {
            forecastDisplay3.src = `img/snowy.svg`;
        } else if (
            weather3 === "Mist" ||
            weather3 === "Smoke" ||
            weather3 === "Haze" ||
            weather3 === "Dust" ||
            weather3 === "Fog" ||
            weather3 === "Sand" ||
            weather3 === "Ash" ||
            weather3 === "Squall" ||
            weather3 === "Tornado"
        ) {
            forecastDisplay3.src = `img/cloudy.svg`;
        } else if (weather3 === "Clear") {
            forecastDisplay3.src = `img/clear-${getDayOrNight()}.svg`;
        } else if (weather3 === "Clouds") {
            forecastDisplay3.src = `img/cloudy.svg`;
        }

        if (weather4 === "Thunderstorm") {
            forecastDisplay4.src = `img/thunder.svg`;
        } else if (weather4 === "Drizzle") {
            forecastDisplay4.src = `img/drizzle.svg`;
        } else if (weather4 === "Rain") {
            forecastDisplay4.src = `img/rain.svg`;
        } else if (weather4 === "Snow") {
            forecastDisplay4.src = `img/snowy.svg`;
        } else if (
            weather4 === "Mist" ||
            weather4 === "Smoke" ||
            weather4 === "Haze" ||
            weather4 === "Dust" ||
            weather4 === "Fog" ||
            weather4 === "Sand" ||
            weather4 === "Ash" ||
            weather4 === "Squall" ||
            weather4 === "Tornado"
        ) {
            forecastDisplay4.src = `img/cloudy.svg`;
        } else if (weather4 === "Clear") {
            forecastDisplay4.src = `img/clear-${getDayOrNight()}.svg`;
        } else if (weather4 === "Clouds") {
            forecastDisplay4.src = `img/cloudy.svg`;
        }
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this pattern :

```js
const getForecast = async (api) => {
    
    const map_weather_img = {
        'Thunderstorm': 'img/thunder.svg',
        'Drizzle': 'img/drizzle.svg',
        'Rain': 'img/rain.svg',
        'Snow': 'img/snowy.svg',
        'Mist': 'img/cloudy.svg',
        'Smoke': 'img/cloudy.svg',
        'Haze': 'img/cloudy.svg',
        'Dust': 'img/cloudy.svg',
        'Fog': 'img/cloudy.svg',
        'Sand': 'img/cloudy.svg',
        'Ash': 'img/cloudy.svg',
        'Squall': 'img/cloudy.svg',
        'Tornado': 'img/cloudy.svg',
        'Clear': `img/clear-${getDayOrNight()}.svg`,
        'Clouds': 'img/cloudy.svg',
    };
    
    try {
        const res = await axios.get(api);
        console.log(res);

        const weather1 = res.data.list[0].weather[0].main;
        const time1 = res.data.list[0].dt_txt.substr(11, 15);
        const weather2 = res.data.list[1].weather[0].main;
        const time2 = res.data.list[1].dt_txt.substr(11, 15);
        const weather3 = res.data.list[2].weather[0].main;
        const time3 = res.data.list[2].dt_txt.substr(11, 15);
        const weather4 = res.data.list[3].weather[0].main;
        const time4 = res.data.list[3].dt_txt.substr(11, 15);

        forecastTime1.textContent = time1;
        forecastTime2.textContent = time2;
        forecastTime3.textContent = time3;
        forecastTime4.textContent = time4;

        forecastDisplay1.src = map_weather_img[weather1];
        forecastDisplay2.src = map_weather_img[weather2];
        forecastDisplay3.src = map_weather_img[weather3];
        forecastDisplay4.src = map_weather_img[weather4];

    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
};
```

but for more flexibility you can use this one :

```js
// array of HTML Element
const forecast = [
    {
        display: /*HTML element*/,
        time: /*HTML element*/,
    },
    {
        display: /*HTML element*/,
        time: /*HTML element*/,
    },
    ...
];

const getForecast = async (api) => {
    
    const table = {
        'Thunderstorm': 'img/thunder.svg',
        'Drizzle': 'img/drizzle.svg',
        'Rain': 'img/rain.svg',
        'Snow': 'img/snowy.svg',
        'Mist': 'img/cloudy.svg',
        'Smoke': 'img/cloudy.svg',
        'Haze': 'img/cloudy.svg',
        'Dust': 'img/cloudy.svg',
        'Fog': 'img/cloudy.svg',
        'Sand': 'img/cloudy.svg',
        'Ash': 'img/cloudy.svg',
        'Squall': 'img/cloudy.svg',
        'Tornado': 'img/cloudy.svg',
        'Clear': `img/clear-${getDayOrNight()}.svg`,
        'Clouds': 'img/cloudy.svg',
    };
    
    try {
        const res = await axios.get(api);
        console.log(res);

        forecast.forEach( (f,i) => {
            const weather = res.data.list[i].weather[0].main;
            const time = res.data.list[i].dt_txt.substr(11, 15);
            f.time.textContent = time;
            f.display.src = table[weather];
        });
        
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a switch statement instead of if/else statements.Its much simpler and a lot less code.https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp

Answer (score 1):

I would probably do something like the following. Never use variables with the same name and just a number differenciating them, use Arrays or Array-like structures instead so you can loop over them:

```
// This is not defined in the snippet you showed us, but it makes it easier to loop
const forecastTime = document.querySelectorAll('.forecast-time'),
      forecastDisplay = document.querySelectorAll('.forecast-display');


const res = await axios.get(api);

res.data.list.slice(0, 4) // If there are more than 4, keep the first 4?
  .forEach(({ weather, dt_txt }, i) => {
    forecastTime[i].textContent = dt_txt.substr(11, 15);
    forecastDisplay[i].src = getImageForWeatherType(weather[0].main);
  });



function getImageForWeatherType(type) {
  if (type === "Clear") { return `img/clear-${getDayOrNight()}.svg`; } // Special case

  const imageMap = {
    `img/thunder.svg`: ['Thunderstorm'],
    `img/drizzle.svg`: ['Drizzle'],
    `img/rain.svg`:    ['Rain'],
    `img/snowy.svg`:   ['Snow'],
    `img/cloudy.svg`:  ["Mist", "Smoke", "Haze", "Dust", "Fog", "Sand",
                        "Ash", "Squall", "Tornado", "Clouds"]
  };
  
  return Object.keys(imageMap).find(key => imageMap[key].includes(type));
}
```

Comment: you code is not as simple to read as it could be, and the complexity is quite high for such a simple problem

Comment: @SimonDehaut The `getImageForWeatherType` method might be a little harder to read, since I tried not to repeat `cloudy.svg` and made the map the other way around. Yours is more clear. But the rest seems pretty short and simple